# C reading formatted text from file

Tags: c, file

i have a question on a C program that I'm doing. The beginning of the track ask this: 
*"Process P ask as argument the path of a file in which every line ust be 16 characters length (included the end of line), and every line must start with "WAIT" or "NOWAIT" followed by a command."* 
The example of input file is:

```
WAIT ls
NOWAIT who
WAIT date
```

I made this code for now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MIN_SIZE 5
#define ROW_LEN 17
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Program usage: %s file_path.\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    
    int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    struct stat fd_info;
    
    if(fd < 0) {
        perror("Error opening file");
        exit(2);
    }
    
    
    fstat(fd, &fd_info);
    if(fd_info.st_size <= MIN_SIZE) {
        printf("Size of file '%s' is less or equal than 5 bytes.\n", argv[1]);
        exit(3);
    }
    
    char buf[ROW_LEN];
    buf[ROW_LEN - 1] = '\0';
    while ((read(fd, buf, ROW_LEN - 1)) > 0) {
        char type[ROW_LEN], cmd[ROW_LEN];
        sscanf(buf, "%s %s", type, cmd);
        printf("type=%s; command=%s;\n", type, cmd);
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

In this way i can read good only if in the file.txt I complete every row with spaces until it reaches 15 characters for each line (else it start reading next line too). But in the file that prof gave us there aren't spaces to complete the row. So my question is, how can I read correctly from the file? I can't understand that "every line must have 16 characters included end of line".
Thanks to all, I hope I explained good the question!

Comment: "every line must have 16 characters included end of line", "the file that prof gave us there aren't spaces to complete the row" Does that means that each line has exactly 16 characters including the end of line (which may be 1 or 2 characters depending on the OS)? Or does this means that the lines have at most 16 characters? Usually a "text file" is a variable length record file (The record being a text line).

Comment: @fpiette at most 16 characters, so it can be 7,8 etc. And that's the point where i stuck, how can i predict with the read() how long will the line be? I made it with fscanf and i can read all lines perfectly, but in lessons he talked about read() for reading files, so i think he wants the read and not fscanf

Comment: You should use `FILE *`, `fopen()`, `fgets()` and `fclose()` to read the file. Those are in `stdio.h`. fgets() will take care of variable line length. It will read a line, and only a single line per call into a buffer. Then use `sscanf()` to read the line items.

Comment: If he wants you to use `read()` you have to rewrite what `fgets()` does. Read one character at a time into a buffer and check for end-of-line (LF or CRLF depending on the OS). So you'll have two loops: one for a single line and one (you already have it) to read all line in the input file. To be more efficient, you can read data in a large buffer and then scan the buffer for each line. This is more complex as a single line may be split in two buffers.

Comment: Really thanks for your support, I try in 2-3 hours this!

Comment: @fpiette reallt thanks, I figured out as you said. I made a buffer of file length size with malloc and stored the entire file in it with a read, then with a loop I found single lines (when '\n' occours), and here I made the control to see if that length exceed 15 characters (without eol). Then stored it with strncpy and saved the two strings with sscanf. Now I can go on, thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly with this sentence you must considerate each line as a possible input, but the input is coming from anyone so anything can append and any errors in consequences.

You start on the good way
you must consider all your file and after your line > check if your line is good

you can use getline to get your file easily, and strlen and strcmp to check if your line is conform.

Finaly the part "include end of line", that mean that all the line must have a length of 16 character with '\0', so in your file the "visible" length must be at 15 for the maximum,

for example if the maximal length is 3 included end of line :
"abc" : incorrect because it's equal to {'a', 'b', 'c' '\0'};
"ab"  : correct because it's equal to {'a', 'b', '\0'};